# option to give multiple arguments to format in python

Tags: python

I have a class method to which I have to pass in image path as argument, 
the method looks like this

```
self.add_image(
    "nucleas",
    image_id=image_id,
    path=os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_id, "images/{}.jpg".format(image_id)))
```

but my folder has both, jpg and jpeg images, is there way it can give options like jpg/jpeg.

I was thinking of using `try`/`except` for the argument, but I'm not sure if that will work.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Do you _know_ the correct extension beforehand? Then you could just pass the extension as a second format paramter. If you don't know the extension, and you just want the path to somehow match both files, I don't see how this is related to `format`.

Comment: `"{} - {}".format(1, 2)` gives `1 - 2` if that is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to give the `Path` module a selection of extensions and have it pick the right one.

I'd suggest writing a little helper function to get the right path:

```
def get_image_path(dataset_dir, image_id):
    jpg_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_id, "images/{}.jpg".format(image_id)
    if jpg_path.exists():
        return jpg_path

    jpeg_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_id, "images/{}.jpeg".format(image_id)
    if jpeg_path.exists():
        return jpeg_path

    # Neither path exists, maybe raise an exception? Or just return None
```

Then in your existing code:

```
self.add_image(
    "nucleas",
    image_id=image_id,
    path=get_image_path(dataset_dir, image_id)
)
```

Comment: This should work, caught up without something else at the moment , will try this and let you know, in the mean time...